# Css "parent" or "this" selector

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Is there some kind of `.this` selector in css?

Or maybe parent selector?

Thanks

Comment: There is no context for this question. You should re-word it before someone closes it.

Comment: give a description of where you would desire to use the .this so we can suggest how to do it, but in short to your answer you cant specify a div using .this

Comment: Just flashed across my mind. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no parent selector in CSS. See [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

Why would you need a `this` selector? It would be redundant, because it implies you have already selected the target element.

Comment: I was just wondering. There is no real example. Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no parent selector existing in CSS.

The only thing existing that comes somehow near to that is this:

```
a < img { border: none; }
```

But this is not a parent selector. This would select a tags but only if they contained an img tag.

Answer (score 0):

well, I don't know if you mean this, but you can always start from the "parent" element, and then go deeper... e.g.

```
div#main_div div#sub_div1 div#sub_div2 span a {
    /* your style here */
}
```

your style will then apply to the a-element. However, only if you have this order (sub_div2 has to be in sub_div1, which has to be in main_div) in your html code as well...